# Plone Testing: Trying to run tests on Products.ECQuiz

Tags: testing, plone

I'm trying to run tests on Products.ECQuiz. There are tests there see: https://github.com/collective/Products.ECQuiz/tree/master/Products/ECQuiz/tests

but when I run the following from my buildout

```
bin/test -s Products.ECQuiz
```

It reports zero tests. I get the following output:

> Total: 0 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors in 0.000 seconds.

Is it because it's an old style product? What do I need to change to ensure that it works?

Comment: It seems that the egg is not defining a `extras` that include Products.PloneTestCase. Try to add it to you [test] buildout egg section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks keul, you pointed me in the right direction.

I had neglected those two things:

.1. in the **setup.py** of the **Products.ECQuiz** package I had to add the following:

> ```
>  extras_require=dict(
>            test=[
>                'Products.PloneTestCase',
>                'zope.testing',
>            ]),
> ```

(I added this just before the `entry_points="""` line).

.2. In my **develop.cfg** file I added the following:

> ```
> test-packages =
>
>      Products.ECQuiz
> ```

My buildout makes use of the values set in test-packages in a [test] section.

After re-running buildout:

```
bin/buildout -c develop.cfg
```

I was able to successfully run the test suite:

```
bin/test -s Products.ECQuiz
```

All tests passed.

> Ran 7 tests with 0 failures and 0 errors in 3.050 seconds.

Comment: Good. So: accept your answer as "the right one" and close this thread.